# Add react routes in application

Tags: reactjs

I implemented some routes in my application:

```js
  <Router>
        <Switch>
          <UnAuthRoute path="/login">
            <Login />
          </UnAuthRoute>
          <RoleRoute path={"/"}>
            <User />
          </RoleRoute>
          <RoleRoute path={"/admin"}>
            <Admin />
          </RoleRoute>
          <Route path="*" />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
```

This routes should respect next conditions:

```css
If user access the application he should be redirected on route -> "/user"
If user try to access the route -> "/admin " he should be redirected on "/404"
If admin access the application he should be redirected on route -> "/admin "
If admin try to access the route -> "/user" he should be redirected on "/404"
If both users try to access "/login", and they are in application they should be redirected on their personal route
```

But i cant figure out why the app does not work. I tried to simulate my app:
https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-mclaren-9vsvh?file=/src/App.js:371-706

 How to fix the code to fit the conditions?

Comment: your `/` route matches the `User` component but since you're not authenticated it redirects to 404 changing that to `/user` might be the solution you need, though the question is a bit unclear

Comment: @apokryfos, i changed the code and i added an authenticated user  https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-mclaren-9vsvh?file=/src/App.js   , but i got `Maximum update depth exceeded`  do you know how to solve the issue?

Answer (score 2):

You need to make few changes to your code to get your requirements working.

- in `RoleRoute.js` you were comparing "undefined" with null(when localStorage.getItem returns null), so you were always redirected to 404.
  Correct way is to compare with null. Like this:

```js
const authenticated = localStorage.getItem("mytoken") !== null;
```

- put exact to `/` route
- make sure to pass `role` prop

Working copy of your [code is here in the sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-issue-fix-wf9rc?file=/src/App.js:341-844)

**Route code snippet**

```js
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <UnAuthRoute path="/login">
            <Login />
          </UnAuthRoute>
          <RoleRoute exact path={"/"} rolez="user">
            <User />
          </RoleRoute>
          <RoleRoute path={"/user"} rolez="user">
            <User />
          </RoleRoute>
          <RoleRoute path={"/admin"} rolez="admin">
            <Admin />
          </RoleRoute>
          <Route path="*" />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
```

**RoleRoute code snippet**

```js
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

export const RoleRoute = ({ children, redirectTo, path, rolez }) => {
  const authenticated = localStorage.getItem("mytoken") !== null;
  const allowed = localStorage.getItem("role") === rolez;

  if (!authenticated) return <Redirect to={redirectTo || "/login"} />;
  else if (allowed) return <Route path={path}>{children}</Route>;
  else return <Redirect to={redirectTo || "/404"} />;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to declare some roles. One for admin, second for regular user and third for non registered user. After that you need to specify the routes for each user

```
<Route exact path="/" component={() => isLoggedIn ? 
      isAdmin ? <Redirect to="/admin" /> : <Redirect to="/user" />
      : <Redirect to="/login" />
} />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also do like this

```js
export const AdminRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) => {
        if (user.role === "Admin") {
          return <Component {...props} />;
        } else {
          return (
            <Redirect
              to={{
                pathname: "/",
                state: {
                  from: props.location,
                },
              }}
            />
          );
        }
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

and then

```
<AdminRoute exact path="/file-upload" component={FileUpload} />
```